# How to setup a Tasker profile to switch ariplane mode at night UNLESS I actually use the phone?

Tags: tasker, airplane-mode

I'd like to switch all radio communications off for night, that is airplane mode.

However, sometimes I drive during night, sometimes I stay awake for late. So it is difficult to set it up just with specified hours. My clever idea is to use more conditions (contexts) than just time.

### **PROBLEM - definition**

How to setup a Tasker profile to keep all radios off during specified night hours UNLESS I actually use the phone?

In a simplistic example, the "*usage of phone*" could be defined as "*screen is ON*". But how about if I'm downloading something, or making a phone/skype call while driving on a motorway during night (and I wish the screen to be off to save battery).

So a more specific **definition of "*phone in use*"** would be a combination of:

- screen is on OR
- pending GSM phone call OR
- pending skype call (or I'm logged into skype account) OR
- pending download via GooglePlay store (or a downloading manager) OR
- at least one active Bluetooth connection.

---

So the tasker profile should do the **following actions**

- run within, say, 22:00 and 07:00, and
- check if one of the above conditions are true.
- if false (i'm not using the phone), switch all radio communications
  off
- if true (I'm using the phone) then do nothing
- however as soon as ALL of those conditions switch to false, switch all radio off

---

Please let me know how you would approach it. I know each phone is different, and I know I need to play around with a Tasker for a while, but as much as I'm good in logical thinking, doing this in a graphical mode instead of text mode seems a bit non-intuitive at the beginning...

### **MY PHONE SPECIFICATION:**

- Samsung galaxy s4 GT-i9505
- Android 4.4.2
- device not rooted (I want to double check one thing with the retailer
  before I can root the phone).

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Profile for each of your preconditions, as well as an entrance Task for each one. The task would simply set a variable (separate for each task).

Then, have an exit task for each precondition. It would clear its own specific variable, and then run the "Airplane Mode" Task.

The "Airplane Mode" task would check all precondition variables. If any are set, do nothing. However, if they are all clear, and the current time is between 22:00 and 07:00, it can safely activate airplane mode.

Finally, have another Profile for the time. When 22:00 rolls around, it will simply run the "Airplane Mode" task. Another one for 07:00 will run "Normal Mode" which would simply deactivate airplane mode.

Comment: I don't think Tasker can check conditions for all of the specific preconditions you mentioned (such as a pending Google Play download), but the logic should work as long as you find the proper conditions to use.